# Enabling validation on your resources in Dropwizard

Tags: java, validation, rest, dropwizard

I am running Java 8 with Dropwizard 0.7

I can't get validation to work on my Resources in Dropwizard

I have the following bean

```
@Data //lombok anntation
@JsonRootName(value="CreateNewGame")
@XmlRootElement
public class CreateNewGameDTO {
    @NotEmpty
    public String name;

    @NotNull
    private GameType type;
    @NotBlank
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    private Integer numOfPlayers;
}
```

And in my Resource class I have the following method

```
@POST
@Timed
public Response createGame(@Valid CreateNewGameDTO dto) { ... }

My JUnit test

@ClassRule
public static final DropwizardAppRule<CivBoardGameRandomizerConfiguration> RULE =
        new DropwizardAppRule<CivBoardGameRandomizerConfiguration>(CivBoardgameRandomizerApplication.class, "src/main/resources/config.yml");

@Test
public void createGameShouldFailBecauseOfMissingUsername() throws Exception {
    List<NewCookie> cookies = performLogin();
    assertThat(cookies.size()).isEqualTo(2);

    Client client = Client.create();

    CreateNewGameDTO dto = new CreateNewGameDTO();
    dto.setNumOfPlayers(4);
    dto.setUsername(null); //Username NULL, so it should throw exception
    dto.setName("PBF WaW");
    dto.setType(GameType.WAW);

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    String dtoAsJSon = mapper.writeValueAsString(dto);

    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromPath(String.format(BASE_URL + "/game", RULE.getLocalPort())).build();
    ClientResponse response = client.resource(uri)
            .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .cookie(cookies.get(0))
            .cookie(cookies.get(1))
            .entity(dtoAsJSon)
            .post(ClientResponse.class);

    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.CREATED_201);
    URI location = response.getLocation();
    assertTrue(location.getPath().matches(".*civilization/game/.*"));
}
```

When I create a unit test to call this resource, I get the following exception

```
ERROR [2014-10-01 11:03:39,515] com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponse: A message body writer for Java class io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.ValidationErrorMessage, and Java type class io.dropwizard.jersey.validation.ValidationErrorMessage, and MIME media type application/xml was not found.
The registered message body writers compatible with the MIME media type are:
*/* ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
  com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
application/xml ->
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$App
  com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$App
```

I haven't done anything to "register" validation. I thought dropwizard was doing this automatically. I haven't found anything in the documentation either.
I am using the 0.7 version of Dropwizard

Comment: Does it work when you skip the lombok part?

Comment: @JanGalinski No of course not. Lombok generates boilerplate code. It shouldn't affect this, and neither did it. Still get the same error

Comment: I am using Java 8, perhaps that is the reason. Although, I cannot imagine why. I have added my JUnit test also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try adding an @Produces annotation to your resource, e.g. @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), either above the specific method or on the whole class and see if that works? I think I've just stubled across the same thing. If it is the case it means that Dropwizard can't determine the MessageBodyWriter to use for a response of that tupe (I think)

Comment: I have already `@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
` on my class resource

Comment: I removed APPLICATION_XML in the Produces and Consumes, and it worked. I think this may be a Dropwizard bug as it should have detected what type I am using, as I am sending JSON as type in the client

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that there is an exception thrown and no exceptionMapper can map this to an valid output. You can try this:

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class ValidationErrorMessageBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<ValidationErrorMessage> {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ValidationErrorMessageBodyWriter.class);

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return ValidationErrorMessage.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(
        ValidationErrorMessage t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(
        ValidationErrorMessage t,
        Class<?> type,
        Type genericType,
        Annotation[] annotations,
        MediaType mediaType,
        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders,
        OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        Joiner joiner = Joiner.on("; ").skipNulls();
        String message = joiner.join(t.getErrors().iterator());
        entityStream.write(message.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
        LOG.info(message);
    }

}
```

Now add in you app run(config,enviroment) method:

```
    // Serializer
    environment.jersey().register(new ValidationErrorMessageBodyWriter());
```

Perhaps you want to modify the BodyWriter to produce other output like xml or sth. else! Hope this solves your problem :-)

---

***EDIT***: Question in Comment

Add this in one of your resources:

```
@GET
@Path("getMBW")
public Response getInTestResource(@Context  MessageBodyWorkers workers)
{
    Map<MediaType, List<MessageBodyWriter>> writers = workers.getWriters(MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE);

    for (Entry<MediaType, List<MessageBodyWriter>> entry : writers.entrySet()) {
        for (MessageBodyWriter  writer : entry.getValue()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("For mediaType '%s' there is a class called %s", entry.getKey(),writer.getClass().getName()));
        }
    }       
    return Response.status(Status.OK).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).entity("get is ok").build();
}
```

Then I get this:

```
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FormProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.MimeMultipartProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StringProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ByteArrayProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.FileProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.InputStreamProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DataSourceProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLJAXBElementProvider$General
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.ReaderProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.DocumentProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.StreamingOutputProvider
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.SourceProvider$SourceWriter
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.server.impl.template.ViewableMessageBodyWriter
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLRootElementProvider$General
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.XMLListElementProvider$General
For mediaType '*/*' there is a class called com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider
```

Comment: If someone asks: The -1 in getSize() -> "A non-negative return value is used in a HTTP Content-Length header. It returns length in bytes or -1 if the length cannot be determined in advance" (source: see MessageBodyWriter description)

Comment: But how come it works when I removed APPLICATION_XML in the Produces and Consumes without this validation error message writer?

Comment: If you remove the produces, then jersey can use another mapper for the requested mediaTypes. Each Client sends Accepts headers and I think, that another mapper was used for output. Perhaps you can verify your client accept header request for reseach.

Comment: I didn't remove Produces, but I had both JSON and XML as produce/consume. I remove XML and only use JSON and suddenly it worked

Comment: Jeah you had no body writer for application/xml, but one for json. Thats why it worked.

Comment: Sorry for all these questions, but I want to learn :) Where is the JSOn body writer? Is it in-built in dropwizard?

Comment: The BodyWriter is from Jersey and Dropwizard uses Jersey. But at the moment, I dont know how to get informations about the jersey built-in features in your app.

Comment: This stackoverflow.com/a/26420051/3280180 is the same problem as above aswered by me!